# Rails system test cannot access location of browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver

Upon running a system test, the following error is documented:

```
.rbenv/versions/2.6.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webdrivers-4.4.1/lib/webdrivers/chrome_finder.rb:21:in `location': Failed to find Chrome binary. (Webdrivers::BrowserNotFound)
```

Examining the chrome_finder.rb file, location method:

```
    chrome_bin = user_defined_location || send("#{System.platform}_location")
    return chrome_bin unless chrome_bin.nil?

    raise BrowserNotFound, 'Failed to find Chrome binary.'
```

thus chrome_bin is not being populated either by the system.platform_location nor a user defined location.

The user_defined_location method implies setting `Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path`

```
  def user_defined_location
    if Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path
      Webdrivers.logger.debug "Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path: #{Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path}"
      return Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path
    end

    return if ENV['WD_CHROME_PATH'].nil?

    Webdrivers.logger.debug "WD_CHROME_PATH: #{ENV['WD_CHROME_PATH']}"
    ENV['WD_CHROME_PATH']
  end
```

How can this be achieved for this rails application?